# Connecting multiple Filter Queries (fq) in Apache Solr

Tags: solr

Let's assume, I have the following documents in my index:

```
title: Entry #1
myfield: 5
---
title: Entry #2
myfield: 2
---
title: Entry #3
```

As you can see, `myfield` is optional and not present in all documents.
Now I want to select all documents where `myfield` is greater than `3` or the field does not exist. Of course there is also a search word let's say `entry`, so it finds all documents.
So the query should return **Entry #1** and **Entry #3**.

Currently I am querying like this:

```
q=entry
defType=dismax
qf=title
fl=*
fq=-myfield:* myfield:[3 TO *]
```

which does not return any documents. Each filter query alone, so `-myfield:*` and `myfield:[3 TO *]` are working like expected.
How can I connect these two filter queries?

Comment: `fq=(*:* -myfield:*) OR myfield:[3 TO *]` should work - you'll have to be explicit about the first set (`-myfield:*`) actually subtracting something from another set - i.e. the set of all documents in the index.

Comment: Thank, works like a charm!

Would you mind posting your comment as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually helpful to think of each term of the query as a set of documents, and the boolean operators as operations performed between these sets (i.e. `AND` finds the intersection between two sets, while `OR` finds the union). A negative set would then be the difference between sets.

When you use a negative match, you have to subtract it from something. When you don't have any other clauses in your query, Solr helpfully appends the complete set of documents (`*:*`) in front of your query. But as soon as you add a second boolean term, Solr can't do that any longer - since it doesn't know what you actually mean with your query.

So your negative clause needs to start with a set that the other set (i.e. the documents that doesn't have field) can be subtracted from:

```
fq=(*:* -myfield:*) OR myfield:[3 TO *]
```